# Wait for calculations to end in excel with circular references

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, vba

I have a number of cells (lets call them Source Cells) that are referenced by another cell (lets call it Target Cell) by its Formula. I change the value in the Source Cells and I want to get the resulting value after the formula in Target Cell is recalculated.

I set temporarily the Calculation to `XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual` and I force a full recalculation by using `Application.Calculate`.

The problem is that when this is executed inside a loop sometimes the formula is not calculated fast enough and the code picks up older values. So what I want is to wait the forced recalculation to end.

I tried the `Application.CalculationState` approach but it is always `xlPending` which makes the program fall in infinite loop. The excel file has some Circular References, the Calculation Iterations is set, and I can see the "Calculate" warning in the Excel Status Bar Constantly (even if I manually recalculate).

I also tried the Application.AfterCalculate event in combination with an Autoreset event but again I ended up waiting infinitely (I suspect that both signaling the event and waiting the event occurs on the same thread, so when wait is executed first the program hangs):

```
    public static AutoResetEvent AutoEvent;
    public static void StartMonitoring()
    {
        AutoEvent?.Close();

        AutoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.AfterCalculate += Application_AfterCalculate;
    }

    public static void StopMonitoring()
    {
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.AfterCalculate -= Application_AfterCalculate;
        AutoEvent?.Close();
        AutoEvent = null;
    }

    public static void WaitForCalculations()
    {
        AutoEvent.WaitOne();
        StopMonitoring();
    }

    private static void Application_AfterCalculate()
    {
        AutoEvent.Set();
    }
```

...

```
StartMonitoring();
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Calculate()
WaitForCalculations();
```

Any better ideas? Do i have any hopes to find a solution with the given excel or should I resolve the circular references?

Comment: The thing with the threads gave me an idea. They do run on the same thread. I'll try to start the whole process on a different thread!

Comment: Personally I would get rid of the circular references as they cause all sorts of problems, not all of which are easily avoidable. Another solution might be to single step the circular calc (something like: set iteration to 2: do recalc until iteration count=1)

Comment: @CharlesWilliams I know but is practically impossible to resolve the circular references.I now trying the AfterCalculate approach and i've put the whole changing the sources watching the target code in a different thread and it seems it gives me consistent results without hanging. The strange thing is that the set is always before the wait... Keep investigating.

Comment: Perhaps you could try adding `DoEvents` before you reset the Calculation to automatic? Also, is CalculationState not returning Calculating after you manually trigger a calculation? In that case, perhaps you could just wait for the state to become pending?

Comment: @NetMage I had thought but it seems due to the circular references and the iteration mode that the state is always xlPending.

Answer (score 0):

If all other options fail
you could try just setting the formulas to Manual and executing the formula in each cell separately with the vb code:

```
  Application.Calculation = xlManual

  Range("NAMED_RANGE_1").Formula = "=10 + NAMED_RANGE_2"
  Range("NAMED_RANGE_2").Formula = "=10 + NAMED_RANGE_1"
```

(Easyer to name the cells as Ranges 1st)
If you want to suppress circular reference warning you could always remove the formula from one of the cells:

```
  Selection.Copy
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are proposing. I do set manual calculations. The excel is pretty complex and there are a bunch of circular references that may or may not are included in the formula I try to calculate.

Comment: By retyping the Formula you are forcing the Formula to Calculate. You can do that in any order You want.  OR you could just make a function that replaces the "=" by an "=" , that will also force the formula to calculate.

Comment: EX: Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Cells.Replace What:="=", Replacement:="="